# How to make Swift 3 recognize a textfield name which is increasing?

Tags: swift, macos

I have 26 textfields which will provide different float values each, and I want to create a loop to make it easier & faster to add those values into a single variable.

My textfields are named a1, a2, ... a26 so the only thing that changes is the number after 'a'. How can I make swift to recognize the textfield name as I'm increasing the variable 'x'.

I was thinking something like this:

```
    var x : Int = 1
    var total : Float = 0;
    var y : Float = 0;


    while (x == 26) {

        y = a/(x).floatValue;
        total += y;

        x+=1;
    }
```

My idea is obviously not working

Comment: Make an array containing all 26 text fields, and iterate over them.

Comment: Even better, *start* with arrays and loops, so you *never* need all 26 to be separate variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array containing all 26 text fields, and iterate over them:

```
let textfields = [a1, a2, ..., a26]
for textfield in textfields {
    total += textfield.floatValue
}
```

Comment: `let total = textFields.reduce(0) { v, textField in v + textField.text.floatValue }` is Swiftier

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yeah, but I purposely chose against it: 1) I decided it would probably be ahead of OPs level 2) if `total` is an ivar, using reduce doesn't buy you much. It still has to be mutable anyway

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jtbandes' comment that it is best to start with arrays and loops, so you never need all 26 to be separate variables.  If your textFields are `@IBOutlet`s, you can use an *outlet collection* (which is just a single array to hold all of the textFields).

```
@IBOutlet var textfields: [NSTextField]!
```

Then you'd simply do:

```
for textfield in textfields {
    total += textfield.floatValue
}
```

---

In the interest of showing what is possible, assuming the textfields are properties of your class (and your class derives from `NSObject`), you can use *key-value coding* to get the values:

```
for i in 1...26 {
    if let tf = value(forKey: "a\(i)") as? NSTextField {
        total += tf.floatValue
    }
}
```

---

Full example for **macOS**:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var a1 = NSTextField()
    var a2 = NSTextField()
    var a3 = NSTextField()

    func total() {
        // give them some values for testing purposes
        a1.stringValue = "1.2"
        a2.stringValue = "2.3"
        a3.stringValue = "3.14"

        var total: Float = 0.0

        for i in 1...3 {
            if let tf = value(forKey: "a\(i)") as? NSTextField {
                total += tf.floatValue
            }
        }

        print(total)
    }
}

ViewController().total() // 6.64
```

---

Full example for **iOS**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var a1 = UITextField()
    var a2 = UITextField()
    var a3 = UITextField()

    func total() {
        // give them some values for testing purposes
        a1.text = "1.2"
        a2.text = "2.3"
        a3.text = "3.14"

        var total: Float = 0.0

        for i in 1...3 {
            if let tf = value(forKey: "a\(i)") as? UITextField {
                total += ((tf.text ?? "") as NSString).floatValue
            }
        }

        print(total)
    }
}

ViewController().total() // 6.64
```